# Работа AJAX ссылка на идентификатор элемента не отрабатывает

Tags: jquery, ajax

Не до конца работает нижеприведенный код. Данные в JSON`e получает, но функция show_question не работает.

```
var answer;
var id_quest;
var III = 0;
var total = 0;
var right = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var right_one_string;
var arrObj =[];
//load_quests();

function show_question(array) {
    // $('#luna').css('border','3px solid red');
    //console.log(array);
    //console.log(array["q"]);
    // console.log(array["explanation"]);
    //console.log(array["w1"]);

    right_one_string = array["r"];
    // console.log(right_one_string);
    $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success hidden");
    $("#expl").attr("class","panel panel-info hidden");
    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
    $("#qb").text('');
    $("#heading").text('');
    var X =0;
    X = III;
    $("#heading").text('Вопрос № '+ (X+1));
    $("#id_quest").text('');
    $("#str1").text('');
    $("#str2").text('');
    $("#str3").text('');
    $("#str4").text('');
    $("#explanation").text('');

    $('#qb').append(array["q"]);
    $('#id_quest').append(array["id_quest"]);
    $("#explanation").append(array["explanation"]);
    var innerArr = new Array();
    innerArr[0]=array["r"];
    innerArr[1]=array["w1"];
    innerArr[2]=array["w2"];
    innerArr[3]=array["w3"];

    var arr = new Array();
    arr= severalRandom(1,4,4);
    for(var i=0; i<innerArr.length; i++)
    {
        $('#str'+arr[i]).append(innerArr[i]);
    }

}
function load_quests() {

    $.getJSON("../ajx.php", function(result) {
        $.each(result, function (i,field) {
            var myArr = new Object();
            id_quest = field.id_quest;
            q = field.quest_body;
            r= field.right_ans;
            w1=field.wrong_1;
            w2=field.wrong_2;
            w3=field.wrong_3;
            explanation=field.explanation;
            var myArr = new Object();
            myArr["q"] = q;
            myArr["r"] = r;
            myArr["w1"] = w1;
            myArr["w2"] = w2;
            myArr["w3"] = w3;
            myArr["id_quest"] = id_quest;
            myArr["explanation"] = explanation;
            arrObj.push(myArr);
        });

    } );
//return arrObj;
}
function severalRandom(min, max, num) {
    var i, arr = [], res = [];
    for (i = min; i <= max; i++ ) arr.push(i);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) res.push(arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length)), 1)[0])
    return res;

}

function show_results() {
    var step =1;
    var id_user;
    var score = 0;
    id_user = $("#id_user").text();

    score = (100*right)/total;
    $.post("../put_score.php",
        {
            'trn': step,
            'id_user': id_user
        },
        onAjxSuccess
    );
    function onAjxSuccess(data)
    {
        if(data=="OK") {
            // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
            alert("При прохождении тренировочного теста\nВы набрали "+score.toFixed(0)+" балов из 100 возможных.");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Произошла ошибка соединения с сервером.\nПопробуйте позже.");
        }
    }


}
function check_answer(id,a_answer){
    $("#expl").attr("class","panel panel-info");
    $.getJSON("../check_answer.php?id_quest="+id+"&answer="+a_answer, function (result) {
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                if(field=='0') wrong++;
                if(field=='1') right++;

            });
        }
    );
}
$("#str1").click(function () {
    answer = $('#str1').text();
    id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
    check_answer(id_quest,answer);
    $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
    if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }

});
$("#str2").click(function () {
    answer = $('#str2').text();
    id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
    check_answer(id_quest,answer);
    $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
    if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }

});
$("#str3").click(function () {
    answer = $('#str3').text();
    id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
    check_answer(id_quest,answer);
    $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
    if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }

});
$("#str4").click(function () {
    answer = $('#str4').text();
    id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
    check_answer(id_quest,answer);
    $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
    if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }
    if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
    {
        $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
        $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
    }

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    load_quests();
    $("#getJSON").click(function(){

       // var questions = new Questions();
        console.log(arrObj);
        total = arrObj.length;
        console.log(total);
        console.log(arrObj[0]);
        show_question(arrObj[0]);
        III++;
        $("#next").click(function () {
            if(III<arrObj.length) {
                show_question(arrObj[III]);
                III++;
            }
            else
            {
                show_results();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Но когда код был в таком виде, то все работало идеально, я просто хотел его немного упорядочить.

```
var arrObj = [];
var answer;
var id_quest;
var III = 0;
var total = 0;
var right = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var right_one_string;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getJSON").click(function(){

        $.getJSON("../ajx.php", function(result) {
            var  i = 1;
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                console.log(field);
                id_quest = field.id_quest;
                q = field.quest_body;
                r= field.right_ans;
                w1=field.wrong_1;
                w2=field.wrong_2;
                w3=field.wrong_3;
                explanation=field.explanation;
                var myArr = new Object();
                myArr["q"] = q;
                myArr["r"] = r;
                myArr["w1"] = w1;
                myArr["w2"] = w2;
                myArr["w3"] = w3;
                myArr["id_quest"] = id_quest;
                myArr["explanation"] = explanation;
                arrObj.push(myArr);

            });
            $("#cont").attr("class", "");
            $("#getJSON").attr("class", "hidden");
            total = arrObj.length;
            show_question(arrObj[0]);
            III++;
            function severalRandom(min, max, num) {
                var i, arr = [], res = [];
                for (i = min; i <= max; i++ ) arr.push(i);
                for (i = 0; i < num; i++) res.push(arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length)), 1)[0])
                return res;

            }

            function show_question(array) {
                right_one_string = array["r"];
                $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success hidden");
                $("#expl").attr("class","panel panel-info hidden");
                $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
                $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
                $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
                $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
                $("#qb").text('');
                $("#heading").text('');
                var X = III;
                $("#heading").text('Вопрос № '+ (X+1));
                $("#id_quest").text('');
                $("#str1").text('');
                $("#str2").text('');
                $("#str3").text('');
                $("#str4").text('');
                $("#explanation").text('');

                $("#qb").append(array["q"]);
                $('#id_quest').append(array["id_quest"]);
                $("#explanation").append(array["explanation"]);
                var innerArr = new Array();
                innerArr[0]=array["r"];
                innerArr[1]=array["w1"];
                innerArr[2]=array["w2"];
                innerArr[3]=array["w3"];

                var arr = new Array();
                arr= severalRandom(1,4,4);
                for(var i=0; i<innerArr.length; i++)
                {
                    $("#str"+arr[i]).append(innerArr[i]);
                }

            }

            $("#str1").click(function () {
                answer = $('#str1').text();
                id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
                check_answer(id_quest,answer);
                $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
                if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }

            });
            $("#str2").click(function () {
                answer = $('#str2').text();
                id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
                check_answer(id_quest,answer);
                $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
                if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }

            });
            $("#str3").click(function () {
                answer = $('#str3').text();
                id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
                check_answer(id_quest,answer);
                $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
                if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }

            });
            $("#str4").click(function () {
                answer = $('#str4').text();
                id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
                check_answer(id_quest,answer);
                $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
                if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }
                if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
                {
                    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
                    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
                }

            });
            $("#next").click(function () {
                if(III<arrObj.length) {
                    show_question(arrObj[III]);
                    III++;
                }
                else
                {
                    show_results();
                }

            });


            function show_results() {
                var step =1;
                var id_user;
                var score = 0;
                id_user = $("#id_user").text();

                score = (100*right)/total;
                $.post("../put_score.php",
                    {
                        'trn': step,
                        'id_user': id_user
                    },
                    onAjxSuccess
                );
                function onAjxSuccess(data)
                {
                    if(data=="OK") {
                        // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
                        alert("При прохождении тренировочного теста\nВы набрали "+score.toFixed(0)+" балов из 100 возможных.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Произошла ошибка соединения с сервером.\nПопробуйте позже.");
                    }
                }


            }
            function check_answer(id,a_answer){
                $("#expl").attr("class","panel panel-info");
                $.getJSON("../check_answer.php?id_quest="+id+"&answer="+a_answer, function (result) {
                        $.each(result, function(i, field){
                            if(field=='0') wrong++;
                            if(field=='1') right++;

                        });
                    }
                );
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Охохо, может какой-то пример скажем на jsfiddle выложите, и чтобы html там тоже был?  Ваш код - "поток сознания", такое тяжело отладить методом пристального вглядывания.

Comment: И да, я уверен это можно сократить раза в 4 минимум.

Answer (score 0):

Допилил до рабочего состояния, проблема была в том, что обработчики кнопок ответов были вне функции document.ready и забыл отменить class "hidden" на контейнере содержащем форму вывода вопроса и ответов.

вот финальный вариант скрипта:

```
//переменные для работы скрипта
var answer;
var id_quest;
var III = 0;
var total = 0;
var right = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var right_one_string;
var arrObj =[]; //массив для хранения вопросов

// выводит в поля вопрос и варианты ответа, принимает массив содержащий инфу об одном вопросе
function show_question(array) {
    right_one_string = array["r"];
    $('#next').attr("class","btn btn-success hidden");
    $("#expl").attr("class","panel panel-info hidden");
    $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
    $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
    $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
    $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-info");
    $("#qb").text('');
    $("#heading").text('');
    var X =0;
    X = III;
    $("#heading").text('Вопрос № '+ (X+1));
    $("#id_quest").text('');
    $("#str1").text('');
    $("#str2").text('');
    $("#str3").text('');
    $("#str4").text('');
    $("#explanation").text('');

    $('#qb').append(array["q"]);
    $('#id_quest').append(array["id_quest"]);
    $("#explanation").append(array["explanation"]);
    var innerArr = new Array();
    innerArr[0]=array["r"];
    innerArr[1]=array["w1"];
    innerArr[2]=array["w2"];
    innerArr[3]=array["w3"];

    var arr = new Array();
    arr= severalRandom(1,4,4);
    for(var i=0; i<innerArr.length; i++)
    {
        $('#str'+arr[i]).append(innerArr[i]);
    }

}
// загружает вопросы через ajax запрос, в JSON`e, запихивает каждый новый вопрос в виде объекта в массив arrObj
function load_quests() {
    arrObj.length=0; //очищаем кеш
    $.getJSON("../ajx.php", function(result) {
        $.each(result, function (i,field) {
            var myArr = new Object();
            id_quest = field.id_quest;
            q = field.quest_body;
            r= field.right_ans;
            w1=field.wrong_1;
            w2=field.wrong_2;
            w3=field.wrong_3;
            explanation=field.explanation;
            var myArr = new Object();
            myArr["q"] = q;
            myArr["r"] = r;
            myArr["w1"] = w1;
            myArr["w2"] = w2;
            myArr["w3"] = w3;
            myArr["id_quest"] = id_quest;
            myArr["explanation"] = explanation;
            arrObj.push(myArr);
        });
    } );
}
//функция рандомизатор (минимальное значение, максимальное значение, количество чисел)
function severalRandom(min, max, num) {
    var i, arr = [], res = [];
    for (i = min; i <= max; i++ ) arr.push(i);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) res.push(arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length)), 1)[0])
    return res;

}
// функция показа результатов, через пост-запрос правит данные в БД,
// инкрементирует значение прохождений тренировочного теста
// и показывает резудьтат, после чего обновляет станицу
function show_results() {
    var step =1;
    var id_user;
    var score = 0;
    id_user = $("#id_user").text();

    score = (100*right)/total;
    $.post("../put_score.php",
        {
            'trn': step,
            'id_user': id_user
        },
        onAjxSuccess
    );
    function onAjxSuccess(data)
    {
        if(data=="OK") {
            // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
            alert("При прохождении тренировочного теста\nВы набрали "+score.toFixed(0)+" балов из 100 возможных.");
            document.location.href='index.php?module=dynamic&page=training';
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Произошла ошибка соединения с сервером.\nПопробуйте позже.");
        }
    }


}
// фукнция проверки правильности ответа на конкретный вопрос, и плюсует соответсвенный счетчик
// работает через ajax
function check_answer(id,a_answer){
    $("#expl").attr("class","panel panel-info");
    $.getJSON("../check_answer.php?id_quest="+id+"&answer="+a_answer, function (result) {
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                if(field=='0') wrong++;
                if(field=='1') right++;

            });
        }
    );
}

// главный обработчик скрипта, "по загрузке документа"
$(document).ready(function(){
    //обработчики нажатий на клавиши ответов
    $("#str1").click(function () {
        answer = $('#str1').text(); //записываем в переменную выбраный ответ на текущий вопрос
        id_quest = $('#id_quest').text(); //очищаем поле с айдишником вопроса
        check_answer(id_quest,answer); // отсылаем по аяксу ответ и номер вопроса на проверку
        $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active"); // делаем клавишу следующий вопрос активной
        // подсвечиваем правильный ответ и неправильные ответы
        if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }

    });
    $("#str2").click(function () {
        answer = $('#str2').text();
        id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
        check_answer(id_quest,answer);
        $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
        if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }

    });
    $("#str3").click(function () {
        answer = $('#str3').text();
        id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
        check_answer(id_quest,answer);
        $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
        if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }

    });
    $("#str4").click(function () {
        answer = $('#str4').text();
        id_quest = $('#id_quest').text();
        check_answer(id_quest,answer);
        $("#next").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
        if($("#str1").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str2").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str3").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }
        if($("#str4").text() == right_one_string)
        {
            $("#str4").attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            $("#str2").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str3").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            $("#str1").attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
        }

    });
    load_quests(); // загружаем вопросы
    // обработчик кнопки "приступить к тестированию"
    $("#getJSON").click(function(){
        $('#cont').attr('class',"");
        $('#getJSON').attr('class',"hidden");
        total = arrObj.length; // общее количество вопросов
        show_question(arrObj[0]); // выводим превый вопрос
        III++; // увеличиваем счетчик
        // обработчик нажатия клавиши "следующий вопрос"
        $("#next").click(function () {
            if(III<arrObj.length) {
                show_question(arrObj[III]); // выводим следующий вопрос
                III++;
            }
            else
            {
                show_results(); // если вопросов больше нет, то вывовдим результаты
            }

        });
    });
});
```